# Can a Monk remain invisible with Cloak of the Shadows while dealing damage with Witch Bolt?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature, monk

I'm designing a monk/warlock character and have noticed a potential synergy.

Cloak of the Shadows says:

> When you are in an area of dim light or darkness, you can use your action to become invisible. You remain invisible until you make an attack, cast a spell, or are in an area of bright light.

Is the action to deal damage with *witch bolt* (after the initial casting) considered an attack? Do any other rules limit the usage of this synergy to remain invisible while continually dealing damage?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Action Economy will prevent this combination.**

*Witch bolt* states:

> ...you can use your action deal 1d12 lightning damage to the target automatically. *The spell ends if you use your action to do anything else.*

Emphasis is mine, to point out the problem- if you go invisible first, casting the spell ends your invisibility.  If you go invisible after the initial casting of *witch bolt*, using your action to do so, you end the spell.

Comment: You could take 2 levels of fighter and action surge...  It doesn't appear the cloak of shaddows requires an action every turn.  If you remain hidden, you do not need to use your action again.

Comment: The problem isn't the number of actions, it's that the spell ends if you do anything with your action besides maintain it, and the Cloak of the Shadows ends if you cast a spell. The two are mutually exclusive in terms of starting, not maintaining them.

Comment: @TheVagrantDog you can start the spell, then use Action Surge to become invisible

Comment: Quoting the whole spell would help here. The spell specifies that it is a *sustained* arc of lightning, which means a clearly visible and enduring line of light between you and the target (which would make invisibility useless). Using any action other than sustaining the arc ends the spell. This is a separate sentence than "on each of your turns" and should be considered a separate stipulation

Comment: @Baergren there's no mechanical difference to having your location advertised by an arc of lightning while invisible and not having an arc of lightning. Unless you hide, they still know your location (but have disadvantage on attacks). Hiding takes an action. Of course, you could ALSO take 2 levels in rogue to subsequently hide as a bonus action. Then it would be up to the DM if the arc of lightning prevents you from hiding.

Answer (score 3):

### Yes

But you have to have a way of getting 2 actions on your turn or of casting *Witch Bolt* with a bonus action.

You need to cast the spell first and then you need to use your action each turn to maintain it. Generally that means you don’t have an action to hide.

However, if you use the Sorcerer’s Quicken meta magic to make it a bonus spell you still have your action free to hide. Alternatively, if you can get 2 actions on that or a latter turn such as with the Fighter’s Action Surge or by being *Hasted*, that works too.

Comment: You haven't explained why @TheVagrantDog is wrong in his assertion (most clearly expressed in his explanatory comment) that using an action for anything other than Witch Bolt will end the spell. All you've shown are two ways that someone could get extra actions.

Comment: @Tiggerous Because these two answers are not mutualy exclusive. Action Economy will, indeed, prevent this combination unless one can get another action/substitute action for bonus action in casting a spell. Dale M describes how to do that.

Comment: @AntiDrondert Extra actions don't help if any Action used for anything other than Witch Bolt ends the spell, they just let you end it even sooner.

Comment: @Tiggerous *..on each of your turns for the duration, you can use your action..* the way I read it, you must spend an action only on subsequent turns. On your first turn you cast *Witch Bolt* with an action/bonus action, use your additional action/original action to use *Cloak of Shadows*. On subsequent turns you use Actions to prolong *Witch Bolt*. Prolonging *Witch Bolt* is not attack or cast a spell action, so it doesn't break invisibility.

Comment: @AntiDrondert If that's Dale M's reasoning, he should include it in his answer.

Comment: Assuming this is a possibility it might be important to note you would still have a "crackling, blue energy" finger pointing to your exact location. I realize disadvantage still applies to attacks but easy target for spells that don't require attack rolls.

Comment: @slagmoth nothing about invisibility says they do not know your location. In fact, it clearly states "The creature's location can be detected by any noise it makes or any tracks it leaves.". You could hide, but then we're looking at another action to fit into the mix. One could be invisible standing on a target, with neon signs pointing at them, be shouting "I'm HERE!!!" and still mechanically be just as invisible as someone doing none of the above who doesn't make the extra effort to take the **hide** action (which *could* allow them to move and the opponent must guess their location)

Comment: @Luke was totally aware of those rules, thanks.